# knockoutjs data binding issues

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to bind list of products by checked values of CheckboxList. My code is

```
<div  data-bind="foreach: featureValueList">
<a href="#">
<input id="" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.SelAttributeList, attr: { value:  $parent.featureId+'-'+featureValue }">
<span class="specal" data-bind="text: featureValue"></span></a>
</div>
```

vm for above binding

```
 {
    "segmentId": "39",
    "segmentName": "Lens system",
    "featureList": [
      {
        "featureId": "48",
        "featureName": "Digital zoom",
        "featureValueList": [
          {
            "featureValue": "14",
            "selected": false
          },
          {
            "featureValue": "20",
            "selected": false
          },
          {
            "featureValue": "40",
            "selected": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "segmentId": "57",
    "segmentName": "Picture quality",
    "featureList": [
      {
        "featureId": "63",
        "featureName": "Megapixel",
        "featureValueList": [
          {
            "featureValue": "10",
            "selected": false
          },
          {
            "featureValue": "16",
            "selected": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "segmentId": "3149",
    "segmentName": "Camera",
    "featureList": [
      {
        "featureId": "5",
        "featureName": "Processor clock speed",
        "featureValueList": [
          {
            "featureValue": "1400",
            "selected": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

server data function is

```
self.ProductsList = ko.observableArray([]);
self.SelAttributeList = ko.observableArray([]);    

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ServiceBridge.svc/GetProducts', 
            data: JSON.stringify({attributeValues: self.SelAttributeList()}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {     
                $(JSON.parse(data.d)).each(function (index, element) {                    
                    self.ProductsList.push(element);
                });                
            },
            error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                alert(msg + '' + err);
            }
        });
```

Now I can't fill ProductsList according to checkbox check. please help.

Edit: Above "featureValueList" is binding correct. When loading first above code works. After i checkbox selection, i want to update ProductsList with server data. please help. Can i use trigger or something?

Comment: Why do you `POST` to a URL that's called `GetProducts`? That should be a `GET` request.

Comment: Also you might want to show your data model. What's `featureValueList`? How does the server response look like? Make a jsFiddle that's functional up to the point where you're stuck.

Comment: @Tomalak, I can't use a GET there. I used this code to bind data. Now i want to reflect changes in SelAttributeList selections in ProductsList

Comment: can you create a fiddle for your problem? I am not quite sure what  you are trying to get to here. Your approach (if the code is copied and pasted) seems little out of place.

Comment: if yo could add your vm to the example it would help

Comment: @QBM5 , vm added. It is working when page loaded. after checkbox check , how to fill ProductsList?

Answer (score 0):

The binding for checkbox is just a T/F value...by just setting it to SelAttributeList you aren't getting T/F values....you need to do set it to something more similar to SelAttributeList.indexOf(featureValue) > -1 ... assuming this variable is a list of featureValues, at least.

Comment: SelAttributeList value is a concatenated (featureId+'-'+featureValue). that is ok. I see that values in antother div. my question is how to automatically update ProductsList with SelAttributeList.

Comment: Where do you create your featureValueList?

Comment: it is coming from a webservice as a string.